# AngularJS Controller: Argument 'controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, require, amd

require.js config:

```
require.config
  paths:
    jquery:"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min"
    angular:"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min"
    controllers:"controllers"
    app:"app"
  shim:
    'jquery':
      exports:'$'
    'angular':
      deps:['jquery']
      exports:'angular'
    'app':
      deps:['angular']
      exports: 'app'
    'controllers':
      deps:['app']

  urlArgs: 'v=0.0.1'
  priority: ['jquery','angular','app','controllers']

require ['angular','app','controllers'],(angular) ->
  angular.element(document).ready () ->
    angular.bootstrap(document,[applicationName])
```

app.js:

```
@applicationName = 'seedApp'

define ['angular'], (angular)->
  app=angular.module(applicationName,[])
```

controller.js:

```
(function() {
  define(['app'], function(app) {
    return app.controller('versionController', [
      '$scope', function($scope) {
        return $scope.version = "this is controller 1";
      }
    ]);
  });

  define(['app'], function(app) {
    return app.controller('salamSasesc', [
      '$scope', function($scope) {
        return $scope.version = "this is controller 1";
      }
    ]);
  });

}).call(this);
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p(style="background: red;") ilie este fermecat

  div(data-ng-controller="salamSasesc")
    h2 {{version}}
```

When i use the 'salamSasesc' controller i get the following error

```
Argument 'salamSasesc' is not a function, got undefined
```

But when i use the 'versionController' everything works fine, i got the feeling that it's related to the AMD but i am not sure

Comment: Have you tried `app.register.controller`?

Comment: why are your app and controllers shims?